# insert circular line into icon circle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a circular icons holder. everything is working perfect but I want to add a circular line that will connect all the icons to create a circle. 
Here is what i want
[image]

Here is what i am currently have
[image]

Here are the codes i am using

```
<div class="three60_wrapper clearfix">


    <ul>
        <li><img src="image url" alt="logo"></li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image url" alt="360 icon"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image url" alt="360 icon"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image url" alt="360 icon"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image url" alt="360 icon"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image url" alt="360 icon"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image url" alt="360 icon"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href=""><img src="image url" alt="360 icon"></a>
        </li>


    </ul>


</div>


.three60_wrapper ul {


    list-style-type: none; 
    padding: 0; position: relative; 

}
.three60_wrapper li {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 2s linear;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}

.three60_wrapper li a{ display: block;
}
.three60_wrapper li img{ display: block; min-width: 130px; height: auto; max-width: 180px;}




jQuery(function() {

    var type = 1, //circle type - 1 whole, 0.5 half, 0.25 quarter
    radius = '20em', //distance from center
    start = -90, //shift start from 0
    $elements = jQuery('.three60_wrapper ul li:not(:first-child)'),
    numberOfElements = (type === 1) ?  $elements.length : $elements.length - 1, //adj for even distro of elements when not full circle
    slice = 360 * type / numberOfElements;

$elements.each(function(i) {
    var $self = jQuery(this),
        rotate = slice * i + start,
        rotateReverse = rotate * -1; 

    $self.css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg) translate(' + radius + ') rotate(' + rotateReverse + 'deg)'
    });
}); 


});
```

it is based one this 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbpas/nz9f9/)

Comment: Have you looked into doing this with SVG?

Comment: If you're not using SVG, you might as well just use the top image and image map it.

Comment: @GaryHayes I think OP also wants the dynamic effect as per the fiddle.

Comment: Guess I should look at it then :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will *nearly* get you what I think you want:

```
li:first-child {
    border: medium solid red;
    width: 24em;
    height: 24em;
    margin-left: -10em;
    margin-top: -10em;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

You would need to experiment more with the actual dimensions. You would also need to add `z-index` values to ensure that the actual icons are in front of the circle.

Comment: it is working for me. that was easy thanks. is there any better solution you can suggest to make this type of cicular icons? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Would not creating a circle and overlapping the existing UL of images over it solve what you are looking for?